# how to append string dynamically and add to requesturl in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a sample request url in that i have to pass parameters as below:

```
"&item_name[0]=" + value + "&qty[0]=" +value + "&desc[0]=" + ""
                    + "&unit_price[0]=" + value + "&item_name[1]=" + value + "&qty[1]=" +value + "&desc[1]=" + ""
                    + "&unit_price[1]=" + value
```

but i am having no clue how to do this dynamically ,Please save me help me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is declaring your url in strings.xml as

```
<string name="url">https://www.xyz.com/name=%s;password=%s</string>
```

and then from java code,

```
String url = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.url), 
                                                           username, password);
```